# How do I keep count of Hot observables?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, observable

I have the following Observable.

```
IObservable<MyDto> observable;
```

Now in order to count the number of items in Observable I cannot use the following code because my observable is Hot and long running and subscription to the 'count' will never be called.

```
var count = observable.Count()
```

I am looking to get the count every time an item arrives, here is something I am trying to do

```
observable.Subscribe(o => Console.WriteLine(" Object received "));
observable.Count().Subscribe(c => Console.WriteLine("Current count is " + c.ToString() + " but this is not final count, more are coming"));
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Scan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212007%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
observable
    .Scan(0, (count, _) => count + 1)
    .Subscribe(count => Console.WriteLine("Current count is " + count));
```